# How to exchange DAI to ETH without paying fee in ETH?

Tags: exchanges, dai

I was trying to exchange my DAI stablecoins to other token, but for that I needed ETH to pay commission. All my assets are in stablecoins and I can not even exchange them to ETH on Uniswap or 1Inch because for that I need ETH. Is there any p2p dApp for exchanging crypto or something that can help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to exchange them back unless you buy some eth so you can pay the gas fee. The miners or nodes are validating transactions like the exchange of your dai to eth you pay them in eth as a 'gas' fee for keeping the blockchain secure and so your transaction gets included in the blockchain. If you don't want to pay a gas fee you can use a centralized crypto exchange like coinbase or crypto.com however even then you'll be paying a trading fee in the US Dollar.